# index view isn't showing

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi I have created a new default index view but it not loading its content and showing the blank page,,, my file structure https://ibb.co/wW337xS

index blade:

```
  @extends('layouts.frontLayout.front_design')

  @section('content')

    <!--html here-->

  @endsection
```

controller:

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use App\Index;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  class IndexController extends Controller
  {
      public function index()
      {
          return view('index');
      }
```

route:

```
Route::resource('/','IndexController');
```

Comment: Your view has no content? Just a comment to it? Inspect the source, what's there?

Comment: does 'layouts.frontLayout.front_design' exist? Your file is named index.blade.php and is in ressources/views/ ?

Comment: @Qirel inspect is showing every thing

Comment: @jtwes yes it exists in it I just wrote @include('layouts.frontLayout.front_header')

    @yield('content')

    @include('layouts.frontLayout.front_footer')

Comment: my file structure https://ibb.co/wW337xS

Comment: Well, then its not actually displaying anything - so add some HTML in there? Replace `<!--html here-->` with some *actual* text, like `<p>Hello world</p>`?

Comment: @Qirel  I just write it as expamle I have lot of code at here like :: <section class="slide1"><div class="wrap-slick1">
   <div class="slick1">
    <div class="item-slick1 item1-slick1" style="background-image: url(images/dw.jpg);">
     <div class="wrap-content-slide1 sizefull flex-col-c-m p-l-15 p-r-15 p-t-150 p-b-170">
      <span class="caption1-slide1 m-text1 t-center animated visible-false m-b-15" data-appear="fadeInDown">
       Women Collection 2018
      </span>

      <h2 class="caption2-slide1 xl-text1 t-center animated visible-false m-b-37" data-appear="fadeInUp">

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Check your routes through `php artisan route:list` and see if your routes match what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Qirel all is well....

Comment: You must be doing *something* wrong if its not rendering. Either with how you access the file, your routes, hard to say really, there's not enough info here for us to know.

Comment: thnx I resolve it it was just spell mistake in code

Answer (score 0):

Its problem is occured, becouse you send user to the view with name of 'index', it means that there is a blade page in the `view` folder of your `resource`, but as i see in your structure, the `index.blade.php` is in this address: `layouts.index`. then you can refactor your controller:

```
public function index()
      {
          return view('layouts.index');
      }
```

Comment: View [layouts.index] not found.

Comment: if you index is in root of views foolder , there isnt any problem in your code and its looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

**wrong**

```
Route::resource('/','IndexController');
```

**right**

```
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
```

Comment: Not true at all. They are both valid, but the resource adds a bunch of useful routes.